# Using input to filter parsed csv through Dictreader

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, data-science

I am new to python and my objective is to create a basic script capable of filtering a csv database through user input.
I searched through various posts and answers and came up with this code that doesn't give the desired responses for some reason, can somebody tell me if it is correct or an erroneous approach? Thank you very much for your help and here is the code below :

```
import csv

from encodings import utf_8
from csv import DictReader
from multiprocessing import Value
from typing import Dict
with open('Book.csv', newline='', ) as file :
    reader= DictReader(file)
  
    for row in reader :
     print(row)
    
  

    ask_age=(input("enterage:"))
    
    for row in reader :
     for key,val in row.items : 
        if ask_age==str in row.items['Age',str] is True : 
         print(row.items['Name',str])
```

Here is a sample of the database (it's a mock database as I am still figuring out the script)

```
Age,Name,Sex
10,brian,male
30,amilia,female
40,raylie,female
```

Comment: So you want a user to enter their name, then you search the dict for their name and if found, you print that row? What is the error or incorrect output you are receiving? Also, post a sample of what the content 'Book.csv' is formatted like.

Comment: @CaptainCaveman Thank for your response. To answer your question, I want to use age (which opened through dictreader becomes a string value) to find the names corresponding to the age. I will update my post in a few minutes for the sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prompt:

```
Enter age: 10
```

Output:

```
brian is 10
```

Script:

```
import csv

ask_age = (input("Enter age:"))

with open('Book.csv', 'r') as file :
    reader = csv.reader(file)
  
    for row in reader :
        if row[0] == ask_age:
            print(row[1] + ' is ' + ask_age)
```

CSV format:

```
|----|--------|--------|
| 10 | brian  | male   |
| 30 | amilia | female |
| 40 | raylie | female |
```

Comment: I have already tried this method and the result is a key error because I have opened it through Dictreader. And a row becomes a dictionary in reader, so I try to call it by key and not by index

Comment: You don't need to use Dictreader. Try this code. It works.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a short example making use of `DictReader`

```
from csv import DictReader

ask_age = input("enter age: ")

with open('Book.csv') as csv_file :
    reader = DictReader(csv_file)
    for row in reader:
        if row.get('Age') == ask_age:
            print(f"{row.['Name']} is {row['Age']} ")
```